# What are the differences between a production system and an expert system?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I've been trying to do some research on rule-based AI, but I can't seem to find a great distinction between production and expert systems. They both use rules to dictate their decisions and they can both use forward or backward-chaining. Yet, they are talked about as if they were seperate entities.

Also, I can't seem to find anything else that fits under the "rule-based system" umbrella; is there anything else?

Any insight on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A production system is a type of programming language. An expert systems is a type of program.

Production systems are a form of declarative programming where you specify what you want done, but not how it is done. Declarative programming works best when your program can be naturally expressed using productions/rules (when/then) and you need to be able to frequently add or delete productions. For example, many email programs allow you to add rules for processing emails when they arrive. It is convenient to use productions/rules for processing emails since what you want done can be expressed naturally as productions (when subject contains "nigerian prince" then move message to junk mailbox), but since you will be adding/deleting productions it is also convenient to maintain them in this form and to allow the process of how the productions are applied to be automatically handled for you.

Generally expert systems refer to programs that emulate specialized human expertise (for example diagnosing diseases). Such expertise can frequently be expressed using rules and can be incrementally added or removed, so these types or programs are often implemented using production systems since it is convenient to do so.

So while production systems have a strong association with expert systems, not all programs written with a production systems are expert systems and not all expert systems are written with production systems.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Seeing as delcarative programming doesn't specify how a task if handled, would it be right to assume that production system languages are relatively high-level? Also, I'm having trouble understanding what may and may not be considered an "expert system". What would be an example of a rule-based program that is not an expert system? Surely, every rule system is dependent on a rule of systems given to it by an "expert" of whatever the program may be trying to solve, no? Again, thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Production system languages are relatively high-level in the sense that you would have to implement a lot of functionality to encode productions in a more conventional programming language. Generally it's not an expert system if there's no domain expert providing the knowledge for the rules. Using rules to process your emails is not an expert system. Using rules to price business products is not an expert system. Using rules to notify you when stocks change price is not an expert system.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, in essence, expert systems and rule-based systems are stucturally identical, but knowledge bases from expert systems are built by experts?

Comment: Yes. Think of expert system as knowledge transfer from a human to a computer rather than from a human to another human.